# htaccess file hit an error

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

when i am includeing htaccess file in my project, it gives an error.

i am using php and mysql.

```
##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

#
#  mod_rewrite in use

RewriteEngine On

Rewritebase /xyz/ 

# For UI Start

### For Index page 
RewriteRule ^index$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^index/$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This is my htaccess file code.

i am working with WAMP.

it gives an error Internal Server Error.

Thanks

Comment: Hi! I am 30 years old. I live in Cologne. It's getting dark outside already, even though it's barely half past five! Winter really is coming. I am currently working on a big PHP project, and wasted half a day yesterday hunting a bug I stupidly inserted myself. I think I'll have fish and pasta for dinner. :)

Comment: Post the htaccess file, where it is stored, and promise to give points to whoever answers this time...

Comment: @Sanjay why do you need to include htaccess file?

Comment: @sandeepan i am using this for url rewrite.

Comment: @Sanjay URL rewrite? Do you mean you're trying to redirect them? You can do that without the .htaccess file.

Comment: It's not possible to answer this unless you show us some code and tell us what the error is.

Comment: @sandeepan and it's all true! :) @Sanjay what I am meaning to point out is that you are not providing *any* meaningful information with which somebody could answer your question. Start with adding the information what error you are getting exactly, and quoting the htaccess file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best thing to do would be to look into the error log file, but I assume you have no access to that.

First of all then, make sure `mod_rewrite` is installed on the server.

Try putting only

```
RewriteEngine On
```

into the htaccess file. If that fails with a 500, `mod_rewrite` is turned off and you need to talk to your provider.

Answer (score 0):

You need not include htaccess files. just put it in proper place. I am sure this is your first time.

Comment: @sandeepan-its in project root folder